# form.is_valid always return false

Tags: python, django, forms, django-models, imgur

`form.is_valid` in views.py always return false. I have used Django forms to create a form and html to implement it.

I will upload this photo to imgur using **imgurpython** later, but first this should work.

**views.py**

```
def upload_view(request):
usr = check_validation(request)

if usr:
    if request.method == "GET":
        form = PostForm()
        return render(request, 'upload.html', {'form': form})
    elif request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            pic = form.cleaned_data.get('image')
            title = form.cleaned_data.get('caption')
            post = PostForm()
            post.user = usr
            post.caption = title
            post.image = pic
            post.save()
            return redirect('feed/')
        else:
            return render(request, 'upload.html', {'error_msg' : "Invalid Inputs"})

else:
    return redirect('/login/')
```

**models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to='user_images')
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=240)
    image_url = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

**forms.py**

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['user', 'image', 'caption']
```

**template - upload.html**

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="loginbox" style="margin-top:200px;">
    {% csrf_token %}
        <p class="text-16">Upload to aperture.</p>
    {{ form }}
    <p class="text-16">{{ error_msg }}</p>
    <input class="login-btn" type="submit" value="Upload"/>
  </form>
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your context has only one variable named `form` so you have to use that only to make your form work.

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="loginbox" style="margin-top:200px;">
        {% csrf_token %}
            <p class="text-16">Upload to aperture.</p>
        <input type="file" accept="image/*" value="{{ form.image }}" name="image" class="login-btn"/><br/>
        <input placeholder="Caption" class="input-default all-curve" rows="3" value="{{ form.caption }}" name="caption" />
        <p class="text-16">{{ form.error_msg }}</p>
        <input class="login-btn" type="submit" value="Upload"/>
      </form>
```

Comment: my forms.py does not have only one form there are so many and plus this method didn't work :(

Comment: @YogeshKumar Your image_url field is causing the trouble. Your form is not sending this field and its empty so that's why its invalid

Comment: shouldn't it be `{{form}}` ? it could be that the name given to fields be different from the ones expected by Django?

Comment: in the meta class all the fields defined can be accessed directly from form object in the template. Also using `{{form}}` is correct but then OP has to add classes and other attributes in the form thus he has to declare every form field explicitly. @SidhinThomas

Comment: yep that's why i said he has to add every attribute to every form field in PostForm class. Also the above one will always work because of default field names. @SidhinThomas

Comment: I did what you guys said, that started working but now it says PostForm has no attribute named image and user and caption. :/ it is not picking the fields from forms.py

Comment: Is it same html template or did you modify it. Edit the question with more details about the current error.

Comment: this is really not the way to save a form. Form can be saved with the form instance you created using `PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)`. also image_url will be empty when you save the form so declare a default for this field in your and add null=True and blank=True .

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="loginbox" style="margin-top:200px;">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <input class="login-btn" type="submit" value="Upload"/>
</form>
```

If this doesn't work, print the `request.POST` and `request.FILES` then update the answer with the contents.